# How can I replace an img in a button with a sprite and have it line up?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change to using sprites instead of icons in my buttons.

Old HTML:

```
<button id="refreshLink" type="button">
<img width="16" height="16" src="/Content/images/icons/fugue/arrow-circle.png">
Refresh</button>
```

Here is my new HTML:

```
<button id="createLink" type="button">
<div class="icon sprite-document-text"></div>Create</button>
```

However I have a problem:  The sprite in the new HTML lines up with the bottom of
the "Create" text in the button. When I use an img then the image appears with an 
equal space above and below it which is what I want.  Is there some way I could make
my div in the first code not line up with the bottom of the text?

```
Using img 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     
x                                x 
x                                x    
x xxxxxx                         x     
x xxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    x     
x xxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    x
x xxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    x
x xxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    x
x xxxxxx                         x
x                                x
x                                x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Using DIV
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     
x                                x 
x xxxxxx                         x   
x xxxxxx                         x     
x xxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    x     
x xxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    x
x xxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    x
x xxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    x
x                                x
x                                x
x                                x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

my CSS:

```
.sprite-document-text { background-position: 0 -990px; }
.icon {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("/Images/fugue/sprite.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
.button{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.167em;
    line-height: 1.429em;
    padding: 0.286em 1em 0.357em;
}
button img {
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way you could use jsfiddle with your code and give us the example?

Comment: I would like to try with fiddle but I don't know how to do the external link to a 16px png.

Comment: Try these from jQuery UI: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `vertical-align` to middle/text-top on the `div.icon`.

Here, I simplified the fiddle a little, and used an online image -> http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/7pyPw/

Comment: Thanks so much and thanks for the fiddle. I will save that link. Works good now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this in your .icon class?

```
background-position:center center;
```

or

```
background-position:center 5px;
```

etc...

Comment: I can't do this as my sprite is 2000 px high. It contains many different images :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are able to put the image at proper place.

The problem is with putting the "create" text at the middle of div.

Add the the following style in icon class

```
.icon    
{         
     vertical-align: middle;    
}
```

This will make the text appear at the middle of div.